# What is the density of log-normal geometric Brownian motion $x=log\left(\frac{S}{K}\right)$

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, moment-generating-functions

If $S_t$ is a GBM with $$S_t \sim LN\left(S_0 e^{\mu t + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 t} , \quad S_0e^{2 \mu t + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 t}\left(e^{\sigma^2 t} -1\right)\right)  $$

Then if $x=log\left(\frac{S}{K}\right)$, is the distribution:
$$x \sim N\left(\mu t + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 t ,  \quad log\left(\sigma^2_{S_t} \sqrt{K}\right)\right)$$

Basically, I am trying to replicate this density, but my variance is never small enough
[image]

Comment: The deterministic $K$ shouldn't affect the variance of $\log(S/K)$.  $\log (S/K)\sim N(\log(S_0)-\log(K)+(\mu-\frac12\sigma^2)t, \sigma^2t)$.